# How to pass an iCalendar object with Django to a template?

Tags: django, icalendar

I'm using `iCalendar` to generate a `.ics` file which I then pass to my template. This works fine, and I end up with a string of the following structure:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDARVERSION:2.0PRODID:-//My%20calendar%20product//mxm.dk//BEGIN:VEVENTSUMMARY:Meeting%20DTSTART;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20130301T050000ZDTEND;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20130301T050000ZDTSTAMP;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20130301T050000ZUID:20050115T101010/info@mysite.comPRIORITY:5END:VEVENTEND:VCALENDAR
```

I can't tell what the best approach to handle this is, though. I would like to make it clickable so that the viewer can add it to their calendar.

An approach that I have tried is just embedding it as a `href` (which does not work as it is not a url):

```
<a class="btn-yellow" href="{{ical}}">Add to my calendar</a>
```

What should I do so that  this is a clicable, add to calendar button?

Answer (score 0):

you're going to want make the href link to the users calendar/email client. easier said than done. if you have a look at how eventbrite does it, actually you could just copy their code, it works smoothly. for example, i don't have outlook, clicking on save to outlook simply downloads the .ics file to my desktop. i do use google calendar and have a yahoo account, clicking on either link takes me to their respective calendars. although i don't like the inline javascript used in the href attribute...a better approach would be to have it link to the ics in the href and then use javascript to redirect the user onclick. this way, if they have javascript disabled, they still get the ics. you can view an example of it in action here: http://www.eventbrite.com/event/5572613838

Answer (score 0):

for the icalendar file that you created to be recognised as icalendar by the client, you need to set the html header `Content-type` to `text/calendar` ([see rfc6047 mime type](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6047#section-2.1)) which can only be done at server side not in your html code.

what you can try in the html code though is to declare a `content-type` via the [type attribute of a address element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#adef-type-A).